# MySQL Filter optimizations, how can I improve my query?

Tags: mysql

I'm still a beginner when it comes to MySQL, but with my mobile application going live here soon I want to make sure that after a couple of hundred people register my database won't catch on fire. What bothers me is all of the iterations of the users table here. (However, I believe they're needed) this one query seems to iterate over the users table 5 times.

Consider that I had 50,000 users. That's (250,000) iterations per query, with the average query execution time being about 0.75/online user/min

(Note: My idea about how the iterations works my be completely wrong)

Here's the query:

```
SELECT * FROM ( 
    SELECT u.user_id, u.name, u.birthdate, u.biography, 
      (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(photo_id) FROM photos p 
        WHERE p.user_id = u.user_id
      ) AS photo_ids 
    FROM users u 
    WHERE u.user_id NOT IN (SELECT q.user_id FROM users q WHERE q.gender = 1) 
    AND u.user_id NOT IN (SELECT q.user_id FROM users q WHERE q.gender = 0 AND q.sexuality = 2) 
    AND u.user_id NOT IN (id_in) 
    AND (u.birthdate BETWEEN (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 20 YEAR) AND (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 18 YEAR)) 
    AND (SELECT q.user_id FROM questions q WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM questions WHERE q.user_id = u.user_id) > 2 LIMIT 1)
) as DT WHERE DT.photo_ids IS NOT NULL LIMIT 9;
```

The goal of this query (Which does its job) is to get up to 9 users from the database where:

- They have a profile picture (Group concat checks this)
- They're between 18 and 20 years old
- They're female and either heterosexual or bisexual
- They have a minimum of at-least 3 questions in the database.

I've been really careful to only return data as I need it the way I need it (Hence the GROUP_CONCAT being used to keep the users photo ids in the same row). In the end only 5 rows are returned. The users table has about 14.

I'm just wondering how I can improve this query, as I'm still learning and I figured this was the best place to ask. Considering the amount of people that have probably been messing with MySQL for years.

After some criticism here is my new query:

```
SELECT u.user_id, u.name, u.birthdate, u.biography 
FROM users u
WHERE u.user_id != id_in
AND u.gender != 0
AND u.sexuality != 2
AND u.birthdate BETWEEN (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 22 YEAR) AND (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 18 YEAR)
AND ((SELECT COUNT(user_id) FROM questions WHERE user_id = u.user_id) > 2)
LIMIT 9
```

Comment: @jkavalik - The issue here is that a join will present multiple rows being returned for the user. (Say if they had three photos, that's three rows). The `GROUP_CONCAT` was used to store photos ids in a comma seperate string to send to the client. The client then downloaded the photos based on id through an AJAX request. I wanted them anyway, so the main goal wasn't to check if it "existed" would returning the multiple rows be more efficient? Or am I missundering something.

Comment: I updated the query in my question, let me know if that is better. (it doesn't have group_concat), but a user will either have between 0 and 5 photos. No more. I simply wanted to send them to the client in the (id,id,id,id,id) format.  The reason for the `DT.photo_ids IS NOT NULL` was because if the user has no ids then the field would return `NULL`. That's fine and all, but remember I'm using `LIMIT 9`. I don't want to return the users that don't have any pictures. That's why I used that temp table / where statement. Is there a better way to do it? Would you recommend just running 2 queries?

Comment: @jkavalik - The reason I'm not using an order by is because the results don't really matter, just the fact that they're filtered. I know I could check for existence of the photo that way, but what about returning the ids of the photo in the row? (Similar to how `group_concat` puts all the ids in the `photo_ids` row)? The users table currently does not have an index, as I'm not sure if it would really be all that beneficial. The options for gender are `0/1` and sexuality has `0/1/2`. Would `IN(0, 1)` be better than `!= 2` ?

Comment: Could you perhaps provide an example of what a join/groupby/group_concat would look like? As stated I'm still a beginner with all of this. I'm really bad with getting joins to do what I want.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93663/discussion-between-hobbyist-and-jkavalik).

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e754f/1/0